# I have 2 queries with only one difference that I want to merge in just one query

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two queries in MySQL that are basically the same, where the only difference between them is a **`min()`** or **`max()`**, I would like to know if it is feasible to join the two.

I believe that the combination of the two will give me again of significant disengagement and less rework.

My goal is to know the "valor_bruto_atual" from the first day and the last day.

**First query:**

```
SELECT 
    titulo_id,
    SUM(valor_bruto_atual) AS valor_max,
    data_imports.data_import AS created_at,
    week(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber
FROM
    ativos_extratos
        INNER JOIN
    titulos ON titulo_id = titulos.id
        INNER JOIN
    representantes ON representante_id = representantes.id
        INNER JOIN
    data_imports ON data_import_id = data_imports.id
WHERE
    user_id = 1
        AND ativos_extratos.data_import_id IN (SELECT 
            MAX(ID)
        FROM
            data_imports
        WHERE
            data_import BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-12-10'
        GROUP BY week(data_import))
        AND data_imports.data_import BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-12-10'
GROUP BY titulos.nome_titulo , weeknumber
ORDER BY data_import ASC , titulos.nome_titulo ASC
```

**Second query:**

```
SELECT 
    titulo_id,
    SUM(valor_bruto_atual) AS valor_min,
    data_imports.data_import AS created_at,
    week(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber
FROM
    ativos_extratos
        INNER JOIN
    titulos ON titulo_id = titulos.id
        INNER JOIN
    representantes ON representante_id = representantes.id
        INNER JOIN
    data_imports ON data_import_id = data_imports.id
WHERE
    user_id = 1
        AND ativos_extratos.data_import_id IN (SELECT 
            MIN(ID)
        FROM
            data_imports
        WHERE
            data_import BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-12-10'
        GROUP BY week(data_import))
        AND data_imports.data_import BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-12-10'
GROUP BY titulos.nome_titulo , weeknumber
ORDER BY data_import ASC , titulos.nome_titulo ASC
```

The only change was the fancy name of the column and the **`min()`** or **`max()`** function inside the where condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
SELECT 
    titulo_id as titulo_id,
-- calculate both SUMs, select values for each dependent by what value it matches to
    SUM(CASE WHEN ativos_extratos.data_import_id = borders.min_id THEN valor_bruto_atual END) AS valor_init,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ativos_extratos.data_import_id = borders.max_id THEN valor_bruto_atual END) AS valor_end,    
    data_imports.data_import AS created_at,
    month(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber
FROM
    ativos_extratos
        INNER JOIN
    titulos ON titulo_id = titulos.id
        INNER JOIN
    representantes ON representante_id = representantes.id
        INNER JOIN
    data_imports ON data_import_id = data_imports.id
-- moved subquery and condition by it from WHERE 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT 
                    MIN(ID) as min_id,
                    MAX(ID) as max_id
                 FROM
                    data_imports
                 WHERE
                    data_import BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-12-10'
                 GROUP BY month(data_import)
               ) borders ON ativos_extratos.data_import_id IN (borders.min_id, borders.max_id)
WHERE   
    user_id = 1
-- removed subquery and condition were there
        AND data_imports.data_import BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-12-10'
GROUP BY titulos.nome_titulo , weeknumber
ORDER BY data_import ASC , titulos.nome_titulo ASC
```

reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224804/i-have-2-queries-with-only-one-difference-that-i-want-to-merge-in-just-one-query/